# Send maven output to file

Tags: maven, windows-7, dependencies, maven-plugin, maven-3

On Windows 7, I am trying to send the output of a **maven-3** command to a text file.

I call the command from the root of the project I am trying to analyze.

The command is:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections -DoutputFile=C:\Users\myname\Documents\output.txt
```

When I run the command without the `outputFile` parameter, I see the output sent to the console.

But when I use it with the `outputFile` parameter, the output file is empty.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Try `mvn -help`

```
 -l,--log-file <arg>  Log file to where all build output will go.
```

`mvn <your parameters> --log-file log.txt`

Comment: Thank you, and to the others how answered. All your answers worked for me.

Comment: There is a way to append the content of mvn command in log.txt file? I mean, each time you run a mvn command and save it in log.txt file, the previous content is deleted.

Comment: Output is no longer printed to console when `--log-file` is used.

Comment: It's possible to print to both ? file and console

Comment: This was my problem! Increasing `Xmx` both in `MAVEN_OPTS` or `argLine` for `maven-surefire-plugin` didn't help. `mvn -l mvn-log-666.txt` worked like a charm! Log file size is about 2.7 MB.

Comment: For those like me wanting to log both to a file and to the console, appending to the file without recreating it all the time, it's pretty easy as long as you are on a UNIX/Linux environment: use tee instead of --log-file: mvn clean install | tee log.txt -a

Comment: When I want both stdout/stderr *and* a file (with a timestamped name) I do this:
mvn ... 2>&1 | tee mvn.log-`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`

Comment: @MaxSpring for linux/macOs you right. The question was for windows 7 ....

Comment: I just used the old DOS Shell redirect > in Windows Terminal like so:  mvn spring-boot:run > output.log

Comment: This does not work if the maven aborts unexpected. For example compiling issues on JDK versions.

Answer (score 7):

Just give it a try:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -DoutputFile=resout.out
```

within the same folder where the pom file is located.

Comment: This somehow stopped working for Apache Maven 3.8.6.

Answer (score 0):

Old school, but it's what I knew.  One caveat is that the mvn command does not return when done to the cli, but for some purposes this is acceptable.

```bash
mvn "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath com.mycompany.test" -Dexec.executable=/Downloads/jdk1.7/bin/java exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec  > /tmp/Out
```