# How to get maven logs automatically?

Tags: maven, logging, command, output

I've investigated how to get maven output logs automatically without passing any additional arguments. For example, to access the output log from a [maven compile command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726875/send-maven-output-to-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), `--log-file log.txt` can be added after the maven command saving the log at a specific directory.

However, I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve such goal without explicitly adding arguments. If it is possible to add arguments in a configuration file, or even override the command behavior.

I searched for something like [hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for git, but I didn't find anything related. Could someone share any knowledge about it?

Comment: You might use `/.mvn/maven.config`? (See [Release notes starting with Maven 3.3.1](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html))..

Comment: Thanks :) It works perfectly.

Comment: Despite the solution, the log is only available in the file disappearing from the terminal. I would like to keep both. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799178/send-maven-output-to-console-and-log-file-using-pom) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to use `-l ...`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried (_-l /{path}/log.log_). The problem is how to keep both logs available.

Comment: I find a way to solve [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799178/send-maven-output-to-console-and-log-file-using-pom/50687660#50687660). However, it works if maven is called by terminal; when called by IDEs, like eclipse, no output is saved.